# TikZ : let ... Could not parse this coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-decorations

I don't understand why ?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\usepackage{pgf}

\tikzset{%
    alamain/.style={%
    decoration={show path construction,%
    lineto code={
        \draw
        let % here his the faulty code ?
        \p1 = ($(\tikzinputsegmentlast)!.333!(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
                             + (rnd*360:rnd*3pt)$),
        \p2 = ($(\tikzinputsegmentlast)!.666!(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
                             + (rnd*360:rnd*3pt)$)
        in
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls \p1 and \p2 .. (\tikzinputsegmentlast) ;
        }
    },decorate
}}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] grid (3,2);

\foreach \i in {0,...,10} {%
    \draw [alamain] (0,.2*\i) -- (3,.2*\i) ;
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general syntax for extending a path in a “curved” way is

```
<start point>.. controls <first control point> and <second control point> .. <end point>
```

and points are usually of the form `(x,y)`. If you are using `\p1` from the `\let` operation, it should be `(\p1)` not `\p1`.

So, you missed parenthesis in

```
.. controls (\p1) and (\p2) ..
```

This works:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\usepackage{pgf}

\tikzset{%
    alamain/.style={%
    decoration={show path construction,%
    lineto code={
        \draw
        let % here his the faulty code ?
        \p1 = ($(\tikzinputsegmentlast)!.333!(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
                             + (rnd*360:rnd*3pt)$),
        \p2 = ($(\tikzinputsegmentlast)!.666!(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
                             + (rnd*360:rnd*3pt)$)
        in
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls (\p1) and (\p2) .. (\tikzinputsegmentlast) ;
        }
    },decorate
}}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] grid (3,2);

\foreach \i in {0,...,10} {%
    \draw [alamain] (0,.2*\i) -- (3,.2*\i) ;
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]